# ExpressJS req.body returns undefined even with body parser

Tags: javascript, express

EDIT: SOLVED! Thanks to Phil, I realized that I had res and req swapped in position!

I'm unsure as to why I am getting undefined when I used both body-parser AND the built in express way.
Tried both methods, but both still returns me undefine when I click on my submit button.

I have done another project prior to this one using bodyParser and the code req.body.name returns me the user input, but for some weird reason, being almost the same exact code, the one below is returning undefined.
Also, when i do try to console.log(req.body.city); I'm returned with:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'city')

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const https = require("https");
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
// app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", (res, req) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  //console.log(req.body.cityName);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

This is my HTML file:

```html
<body>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <label for="cityInput">City Name:</label>
        <input id="cityInput" type="text" name="cityName" placeholder="cityname">
        <button type="submit" name="button">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: **Just a TYPO**. You've got the argument's backwards... it's `(req, res)`, not `(res, req)`

Comment: Omg thank you Phil!!!! Did not expect that! Was stuck on this for 2 hours!!

Comment: @JiaLi You may want to delete the question in that case, it'll unlikely help anyone else in the future

Comment: I highly recommend switching to Typescript. You'll make far fewer simple mistakes like this